# Using SliceBuilder with Elastic RestHighLevelClient to achieve parallelism in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I need to fetch more than 1,000,000 records from Elasticsearch using Java RestHighLevelClient

I am using scroll for pagination and everything is working fine.

Code Looks like something this:

```
class ScrollTest {

final static RestHighLevelClient client = LocalhostClient.create();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    long st= System.currentTimeMillis();

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("movies_data");
   

    QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(new MatchAllQueryBuilder());

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);

    searchSourceBuilder.size(10000); //max is 10000

    searchRequest.indices("movies_data");

    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

    final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(5l));

    searchRequest.scroll(scroll);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
    SearchHit[] data = new SearchHit[0];

    SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

    while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) {

        // funcation for  conatcting results

        SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);

        scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);

        searchResponse = client.scroll(scrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();

        searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        System.out.println("###################"+searchHits.length);

    }

    ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest();
    clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
    ClearScrollResponse clearScrollResponse = client.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
   
    System.out.println("Time Taken"+(System.currentTimeMillis()-st));

}
```

}

But Fetching large number of document using scroll is taking a lot of time  since its querying for every 10000 documents so end-up with 100 request. Overriding the default windows size values also not helped much ( tried with 100, 1000, 10000 and 25000)

I want to make request fetching parallel at least within page using [slice scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-scroll.html#sliced-scroll), but missing how to use it with scroll.

Can someone please guide how to use slice builder to achieve parallelism ?